# Netty not closing channels normaly

Tags: java, netty, high-load

I'm new with Netty. Now migrating my server, cause of high loads. I read lots of mans, doing everything like in examples, but have a bug: CPU load grows in time and very fast.

Analyzing heap and logs shows me, that channels, which throws exceptions (may be not only them) not closing normally, and keeps in worker's selectors. I got 150+ opened channels with 50 users online.

My code is follows.

Creating server:

```
networkServer = new ServerBootstrap(new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(bossExec, ioExec, 4));
networkServer.setOption("backlog", 500);
networkServer.setOption("connectTimeoutMillis", 10000);
networkServer.setPipelineFactory(new ServerPipelineFactory());
Channel channel = networkServer.bind(new InetSocketAddress(address, port));
```

Pipeline factory:

```
@Override
public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
    PacketFrameDecoder decoder = new PacketFrameDecoder();
    PacketFrameEncoder encoder = new PacketFrameEncoder();
    return Channels.pipeline(decoder, encoder, new PlayerHandler(decoder, encoder));
}
```

Decoder:

```
public class PacketFrameDecoder extends FrameDecoder {
@Override
public void channelClosed(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
}

@Override
public void channelDisconnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
}

@Override
protected Object decode(ChannelHandlerContext arg0, Channel arg1, ChannelBuffer buffer) throws Exception {
    try {
            buffer.markReaderIndex();
        Packet p = // ... doing decoding things
        if(p != null)
            return p;
                    // Reset buffer if not success
        buffer.resetReaderIndex();
            // Reset buffer if not success and got exception of not enough bytes in buffer
    } catch(BufferUnderflowException e) {
        buffer.resetReaderIndex();
    } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aioobe) {
        buffer.resetReaderIndex();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

And handler:

```
@Override
public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
    worker = new PlayerWorkerThread(this, e.getChannel());
}

@Override
public void channelDisconnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
    worker.disconnectedFromChannel();
}

@Override
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {
    if(e.getChannel().isOpen())
        worker.acceptPacket((Packet) e.getMessage());
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e) {
    Server.logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Exception from downstream", e.getCause());
    ctx.getChannel().close();
}
```

Everything is working very well, except growing cpu load...

Comment: I think you're going to have to narrow things down a bit.

Comment: I don't understand, what you mean. And sorry for my bad English...

Comment: The example code is too long. Please try to provide the minimum amount you need that compiles and demonstrates the problem.

Comment: It is impossible provide code that compiles. Example will be much longer. And you also can't simulate the problem, I think. I cleaned as much as I can.

Comment: I found other memory leak in my program, witch keeps channels in heap. Question closed.